# Detect change to router.isNavigating

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to add a `class` to the `html` element when Aurelia is navigating to a new route so that I can style the page differently when it's loading.

My current solution is to add the class to the `main` element because that's part of my View and so it "just works", like this:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class App {
    constructor (router) {
        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

And then in my view I simply do:

```
<main class="${router.isNavigating ? 'loading' : ''}">
    <router-view></router-view>
</main>
```

But, like I mentioned, I would prefer to add the `loading` class to the `html` element instead (so that I can style every single decendant on the page). Since the `html` element is *not* part of my view I can't accomplish this the same way, but instead I need to `document.documentElement.classList.add('loading')` whenever `router.isNavigating` is true.

So my question is; how can I accomplish  this? I know aurelia supports `propertyChanged` methods but I'm not sure how it works when it's a nested property like `router.isNavigating`, `routerIsNavigatingChanged()` does not work. I've also tried `@computedFrom(router)` and variants of that but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I ended up solving this using the `EventAggregator` instead;

```
this.ea.subscribe('router:navigation:processing', event => {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('loading');
});

this.ea.subscribe('router:navigation:success', event => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('loading');
});
```

I'm not sure it's the best solution but it seems to work. Would still like to know whether it's possible to do `@computedFrom('router.isNavigating')` because trying that throws errors.

Comment: Fabio's answer above is the equivalent of doing `@computedFrom('router.isNavigating')`, but I think the solution using the EventAggregator is the correct way to do this.

Comment: I agree with @AshleyGrant.

Comment: guys let me ask.. using 'isNavigating' for show/hide the spinner supposing i have an api call in attached event.. the spinner will hide even if my call was not ended yet?

Comment: How do you unsubscribe to the event aggregator?

Comment: Store the return value of the subscribe method and then call dispose() on it.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution could be using the BindingEngine, but I think that EventAggregator is a better solution. I'm posting this here just for your curiosity.

```
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-binding';

export class App {

  static inject = [BindingEngine];

  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }

  configureRouter(config, router) {
      //...
      this.router = router;        
  }

  attached() {
    this.navigationSubs = this.bindingEngine
      .propertyObserver(this.router, 'isNavigating')
      .subscribe(this.isNavigationChanged);
  }

  detached() {
    this.navigationSubs.dispose();
  }

  isNavigationChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      document.documentElement.classList.add('loading');
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('loading');
    }
  }

}
```

In addition, I'm not sure if setting `class` of the `html` is good idea.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's good for future reference. But if you both think the EA is the way to go I guess I'll give myself the answer.

Comment: I missed your comment regarding adding an HTML class. I love doing that when it comes to global style state. Like if a popup is open, or the page is loading, or whatever. Setting a class on `<html>` allows me to not only style the root element bu every single child as well. When it comes to `html.loading` all I do is show a spinner. Adding the class to the actual spinner instead would limit my styling options and tightly couple my app.js with my spinner HTML so I definitely prefer the `html.loading` approach.

Comment: I see. Well, I would add `loading` to the `<body>` instead, but this is just my opinion. If it solves your problem and you like it, do it :D